# Decimal javascript-toFixed

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some labels "span" with the price (0.9; 1.23; 9.0) of my "products", I use the method "toFixed (2)" to have two decimal places.
The problem is that now all my prices are the same value : 0.90.
What should I do to make the method "toFixed" take my "spans" separately?
My code:

```
//show two decimals
  var price = parseFloat($('.unit_price_d').text()); //span 
  var price_d = (price).toFixed(2);
  console.log(price_d);
  $('.unit_price_d').text(price_d);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok, good question!

```
var price = 0
$('.unit_price_d').each(function(){
    price_d = parseFloat($(this).text()).toFixed(2); //span 
    console.log(price_d);
    $(this).text(price_d)
})
```

Note two things. iteration with `*.each()*` and `*this*` keyword,
code-on!

Comment: thank you very much guys: D, I'm starting as a front-end developer and I am still new to some things

Comment: Why using `map()` over `each()`? Which I think is more performant and here more logical as well. And you should avoid declaring variables in iterators.

Answer (score 3):

You can give a function to the `.text()` method. It receives the old text contents of each selected element as an argument, and the return value replaces it.

```
$('.unit_price_d').text(function(i, oldtext) {
    return parseFloat(oldtext).toFixed(2);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should loop into your DOM elements and apply the `toFixed()` for each specific elements texts. Like:

```
var price = 0
$('.unit_price_d').each(function() {
  price = parseFloat($(this).text()).toFixed(2)
  $(this).text(price)
})
```

Although, I would recommend using data attributes on your span to be a bit cleaner and keep both values in your markup: `<span data-price="1.23"></span>`.

Finally, if you're beginning JS, you should consider trying to code a bit without jQuery, in order to better understand DOM manipulation (and JS globally).

Comment: thank you very much guys: D, I'm starting as a front-end developer and I am still new to some things